# como realizar un update con un input de un swal en ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

buenos dias tengo una duda tengo un swal que me trae una caja de texto el cual necesito que  al rellenar ese campo haga un update dentro de la base de datos ... se que las cajas de texto tienen un **id** y entiendo que ahi va el nombre de la caja con q capturaremos la informacion para llevar a la bd ... pero en este cod solo tiene  **content: "input"**   que es la caja de texto como coloco el **id** con el que capturaria la informacion de esa swal ?

codigo :

```
swal({
title: "informacion",text: "Motivo",icon: "info",content: "input", buttons: 
 {cancel: true,confirm: true,cancel: 
    {text: "Cancelar",visible: true}
       },
        })
```

le agradecería mucho de su ayuda

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

```js
Swal.fire({
    title: 'Modal Motivo',
    input: 'text',
    inputLabel: 'Escriba el motivo de solicitud :',
    inputPlaceholder: "Cual es el motivo ?",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#33215f',
    cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Guardar',
    allowOutsideClick: false,
    inputValidator: (value) => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            if (value) {
                var valor_recibido = value
                resolve()

                console.log(valor_recibido)
                //Se escribe la funcion a enviar los datos [ Valor_recibido ] o aqui mismo se escribe el algoritmo a seguir.
                //----------------------------------
            } else {
                resolve('Por favor escriba el Motivo')
            }
        })
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.3.0/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: amigo una pregunta ahora sabemos que en js recibimos el id de la caja de texto mediante la etiqueta id=" ", dentro de la caja de texto cierto ? para luego pasarla por js mediante  data: "motivo"+"motivo=" cierto ?

como capturo en esta caja de texto **input: 'text'** la informacion del motivo ? para pasarla por la data ?